# Firebase Database - Add Index on "dynamic" child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase Database to store the scores of a game. All is working fine until I've decided to implement a "weekly score".

In order to be able to filter by score and then order by weekly, I'm storing the data in the following structure:

```
game_scores-weekly
    2018-01-29
        user_id: { score, date, bla, bla bla}
        user_id: { score, date, bla, bla bla}
        user_id: { score, date, bla, bla bla}

    2018-02-05
        user_id: { score, date, bla, bla bla}
        user_id: { score, date, bla, bla bla}
```

So, this works just fine but I get that annoying warning every new week about performance issues due not having indexes on "game_scores-weekly/new_week" indexOn "score". Manually adding the index works... until the next week, so not an option.

```
    "game_scores-weekly": {
      "2018-02-19": {
        ".indexOn": ["score", "uid"]
      },
      "2018-02-12": {
        ".indexOn": ["score", "uid"]
      }
    }
```

Is there any way to specify somehow a wildcard in the date, so it works for any new date? or perhaps can I programatically create the new index every week, or is there any other solution I might have not thought about?

Also, thought of manually creating list of all weeks of the year and adding it in one go, but likely would be a limit?

Last, but not least, I'm only interested on current week and last week scores, anything older I'd like to keep it to have some historical data but I don't query it in the game, so could potentially get rid of indexes of older weeks.

Cheers!

Comment: What stands out odd to me is the fact that you do not store them as a child of the user.

Comment: I also store a timestamp of when score was posted in the child of the "Score entry", but as far as I understood from docs/reading, you can't filter by one field and then sort by another one in same query. having to deal with one or the other in the logic of the app, which is not efficient/viable when dealing with large records.

Comment: I know in Firebase functions you can use brackets to specify a changing value. In your case: `game_scores-weekly/{date}/user_id` . Might be able to do the same thing in other SDKs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to @Tristan for pointing me in the right direction.

I used the following code to define the index and now warning is gone:

```
"game_scores-weekly": {
  "$date": {
    ".indexOn": ["score", "uid"]
  }
}
```

Seems super obvious now but couldn't find anything clear in the documentation.

Note that `$date` could be any name really, seems like you can specify a variable value using any `$identifier`.